# How to right two lags periods?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question about R; I would like to use two lags periods instead of one (please check my below code) in my model but I don't know how to write it in R.  Can someone help please?

Here below are details of my R code:

```
library(plm)
fixed = plm(sp ~lag(debt)+lag(I(debt^2))+outgp+gvex+vlimp+vlexp+bcour+infcpi, data=pdata, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")
```

The lags must be on the variable debt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give 2 lags on the `debt` variable.

```
library(plm)
    
fixed = plm(sp ~lag(debt, k=1:2)+lag(I(debt^2))+outgp+gvex+vlimp+vlexp+bcour+infcpi, data=pdata, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")
```

For example:

```
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
lags2mod <- plm(inv ~ lag(value, k=1:2) + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within")
```

`summary(lags2mod)`

```
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = inv ~ lag(value, k = 1:2) + capital, data = Grunfeld, 
    model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n = 10, T = 18, N = 180

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-272.21434  -19.24168    0.42825   18.09930  260.85548 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
lag(value, k = 1:2)1  0.078234   0.015438  5.0677 1.059e-06 ***
lag(value, k = 1:2)2 -0.018754   0.016078 -1.1664    0.2451    
capital               0.352658   0.021003 16.7910 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    2034500
Residual Sum of Squares: 617850
R-Squared:      0.69631
Adj. R-Squared: 0.67449
F-statistic: 127.633 on 3 and 167 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

Comment: @Pradanna S,thanks so much for your help, thanks again.

Comment: @EmilioDas, Sure. Kindly accept my answer and upvote!!